# Auto layout delayed on label

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, autolayout, swift2

I have a calculator app (just like the apple in-built calculator app) and I used auto-layout. Everything is working fine in portrait mode but when I rotate the screen to landscape the UIButtons resize according to the screen size but the `UILabel` that show result resizes after a delay, i.e. when I rotate the screen to landscape mode the `UITextField` also rotate but the size of `UITextField` is same as the portrait size for 2 seconds and then it resizes correctly.

Is it something related to hugging priority or compression priority?

The content hugging priority
Horizontal - 251
Vertical - 251

Content compression resistance priority
Horizontal - 750
Vertical - 750

Hope you understand the question
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

see the second screenshot the display (i.e. the zero is not towards the margin but at the middle but after 2 seconds it sizes correctly.)

Comment: @Maulik Can you pls explain. I did not understand.

Comment: do you know about size classes?

Comment: @Maulik yes. But my problem is delay in the expand of the label

Comment: plz give me portrit & landsape screen shot & then tel me what is the problem

Comment: @Maulik added screenshots

Comment: @Maulik i am sorry but the delay is of 2 seconds it is the only way I can take screenshot. But it shows the problem look at the result label it is not in the right end, wheareas all the buttons are placed correctly

Comment: upload after 2 second screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91723/discussion-between-maulik-and-user2413621).

Comment: which version you use....ios 9 ..if you use ios 9 then check on ios 8

Comment: yes ios9. added 3rd screenshot

Comment: check on ios 8...if there is no problem on ios 8 then report that bug on apple..

Comment: @Maulik I dont have a ios8 device, but I tested it on ios7.1 device and its working fine.

Comment: yes...then there is a problem on ios 9... report on apple site..as bug..

Comment: @Maulik any workaround for this issue

Comment: just report bug...it's not our fault...